# Enviar un correo electrónico cuando el backup en mysql se haya realizado

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, mysqldump

Tengo un cron para respaldar una base de datos a través de mysqldump. Necesito agregar la instrucción que envié un correo electrónico para notificar si el backup fue exitoso o fallo.

El script que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
   #!/bin/sh 
FECHA=`/bin/date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`
SERVIDOR="$(hostname)"
PASSWORD='password'
ARCHIVO=$SERVIDOR-DBSTBASEPRUEBA-$FECHA.sql


mysqldump --databases BasePrueba --no-data --triggers --routines --events --disable-keys  --lock-tables=false --user=user -p$PASSWORD > /tmp/$ARCHIVO

##Declaro una funcion para enviar por correo electronico
envia_correo()
{
        ##Declaro y asigno mis variables con los valores que le asigno por defecto
        PARA_ENVIAR=1
        FECHA=`/bin/date +\%d-\%m-\%Y`
        CORREO_DESTINATARIO=correo@hotmail.com
        CORREO_COPIA=correo@hotmail.com
        NOMBRE_SERVIDOR="$(hostname)"
        ##Pregunto si el codigo de salida del respaldo es igual a 0
          if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
        then
          ASUNTO_CORREO="El respaldo diario de la base de datos en $SERVIDOR  se realizo correctamente" 
          CUERPO_MENSAJE="El respaldo diario de la base de datos en $SERVIDOR se realizo correctamente"
        else
          ASUNTO_CORREO="El respaldo diario de la base de datos en $SERVIDOR  no se realizo correctamente"
          CUERPO_MENSAJE="El respaldo de la base de datos en $SERVIDOR no se realizo correctamente"
        fi
        ##Pregunto si la variable para enviar es igual a 1
        if [ $PARA_ENVIAR -eq 1 ]; then
                mail -s "$ASUNTO_CORREO" -c "$CORREO_COPIA" "$CORREO_DESTINATARIO" <<< "$CUERPO_MENSAJE"
        fi
}
```

El respaldo se genera correctamente pero no envía la notificación por correo, me pueden asesorar si hay algún error en la manera que se esta programando?

Les agradeceré bastante si me pueden dar una mano. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Acaso el backup no se realiza mediante un Cron Job? Pues en la definición del Cron Job indica que te mande un email cada vez que éste se ejecute.

Answer (score 1):

En tu código sólo estás declarando la función que envía el mensaje, pero nunca la llamas. Sólo tienes que agregar

```
envia_correo
```

al final de tu código.